# Why am I getting a mean higher than the highest value that should be in the dataset?

Tags: r, statistics

I wrote a code in R to run an experiment 1000 times and determine how many times the p value was less than .05 and save that. The next question asked was find the mean of that value. The mean I am getting is higher than .05 which obviously means I made a mistake that I am having trouble spotting. Where is my error?

```
set.seed(100)
pvals <- replicate(1000,replicate( 20, {

cases = rnorm(10,30,2)
controls = rnorm(10,30,2)
t.test(cases,controls)$p.value
}))

x <- sum(pvals<=0.05)
mean(pvals<=0.05)
```

the result -> .05035

Comment: Just look at what `pvals<=0.05` returns. It doesn't return the p-values less than 0.05, it returns TRUE or FALSE whether or not that p-value is less than 0.05. Taking the mean() of that basically just give you the proportion of values less than 0.05, not the mean of that subset.

Comment: Thank you. Just so I have a full understanding of what is going on let's just say i want to gather all the values less than .05. If I use as.numberic I simply get 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE. How would I gather those values?

Comment: You do what Duck did in their answer. You subset with []. So `pvals[pvals<0.05]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:

```
mean(pvals[which(pvals<=0.05)])
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.02539414
```

Also with same result:

```
mean(pvals[pvals<=0.05])
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.02539414
```